# Swapping input elements with jquery, not retaining values

Tags: jquery, swap

I have a form builder with up/down arrows to swap positions. Everything is working correctly except that any new input typed in the textarea or input field is not retained when making the switch.

Here's the code to swap an object upwards

```
$("a.move-up").live('click', function() {
      var xvalue = $(this).attr("xvalue");
      var this_row =  $("tr#row-" + xvalue).html();
      this_row = "<tr id='row-" + xvalue + "'>" + this_row + "</tr>";


      var position = $("table#input-table tr").index($('tr#row-' + xvalue));
      position++;

      var prev_position = position - 1;

      $("#input-table tr:nth-child(" + position + ")").remove();
      $(this_row).insertBefore("#input-table tr:nth-child(" + prev_position + ")");

      //alert(this_row);


      return false;

   });
```

Comment: Can you add some html? It seems you're doing a lot of html-changes which are not necessary. (the removing and re-adding is probably what's killing your input value)

Answer (score 1):

All you really need to do is move the whole row as a jQuery object, without needing to reconstruct it in html strings. When using jQuery it is important to understand that the `$(selector)` object contains full DOM elements with many more properties than the html that makes it up

```
$("a.move-up").live('click', function() {
    var xvalue = $(this).attr("xvalue");
    var this_row = $("tr#row-" + xvalue)
    var prev_row = this_row.prev();
    this_row.inserBefore(prev_row);

    return false;

});
```

If the `move-up` button is within the row you can use a simple traverse to identify the current row and simplify code even more

```
$("a.move-up").live('click', function() {

    var this_row = $(this).closest('tr')
    var prev_row = this_row.prev();
    this_row.inserBefore(prev_row);

    return false;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You miss those values because they are not part of the HTML code returned by the html() method. You have to rewrite these values manually. Try to change the beginnig of your function to something like:

```
var this_row =  $("tr#row-" + xvalue);
var new_row = "<tr id='row-" + xvalue + "'>" + this_row.html() + "</tr>";
this_row.find("input[type=text], textarea").each(function(index){
    $(new_row.find("input[type=text], textarea")[index]).val( $(this).val() );
});
this_row = new_row;
```